# React native expo eas build, application doesn't work on my device

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I created a react native expo base application, and build that with below command, It's rendered a .apk file and it's sucessfuly installed on my device, but when i want to run application, the app will stopped many times and can not reach.

I tried the below command:

###### The command:

```
npx eas build -p android --profile preview
```

Also The below code is my aes.json and app.json

###### eas.jso:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

###### app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "cilivo-demo",
    "slug": "cilivo-demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.miladpegah.cilivodemo"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.miladpegah.cilivodemo"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "be464201-ce1f-4105-b4be-1800ba52cde6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```